# Wordpress theme blocking Javascript widget from displaying

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to implement this widget into a client's website.

This is the widget: http://www.tripadvisor.com/Widgets-g294458-d6694228-c6-a_widgetKey.selfserveprop-Interesting_Times_Bureau-Bucharest.html

This is the page with the widget: http://interestingtimes.ro/tripadvisortest/

The theme is blocking the Javascript. I switched to the default wordpress theme and it was working ok.

Any suggestions?

PS: I renamed the plugins folder to deactivate them, but it did not work.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: I know it's a jquery error!  For example if I delete the wp-includes -> js -> jquery.js  file, it works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will want to edit your question and include any code you're already trying or what steps you have taken. I suspect the theme is not the problem, yet how the theme executes JavaScript. Remember that JQuery is just a framework for JavaScript. If there is a conflict or error, all of it may not load.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your Javascript is being deferred to the footer, and cached. I wonder if your theme is making the JS cache... I see you are on the Jupiter theme, seen here: http://support.artbees.net/support/solutions/articles/1000089339-how-to-add-custom-css-and-javascript

You can try inserting how their support recommends, via the custom box. You can also do a crazy workaround, though not awesome for SEO - create an html page, insert the code into the blank html page, and iframe it into the page you need it on. This causes the JS to execute in a separate environment, so the JS caching that Jupiter theme is doing will not affect it.

I personally dislike themes that do that with JS, having a theme too JS dependent is rough on mobile, and can be rough with plugin conflicts, it is more for people looking for the JS features, and do not mind operating within the tightly predetermined confines of the theme.